# What combination do you set on the door to open it in "The Claw"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What is the combination you need to set on the door in the "Black Falls Sanctum" to open it with the golden claw?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To figure out the puzzle of the Golden Claws you can examine them in your inventory. Here is an image to the one you are speaking of:

[image]

Just arrange the door rings like you see on the claw and voila.

Comment: I was wondering where the solution was to be found, didn't know it was this obvious... I managed by trial and error

Comment: Does the solution vary per instance of the game? I've heard some talk about it being randomized.

Comment: the picture shows the same combination I used in my luggage... er door, so either by pure chance I got the same or its not randomized at all

Comment: I can't get the rings to rotate...this a glitch?

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's not randomized, got the same image with my second character.

Comment: just a youtube link to make it easier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrU_hdRdaE8