# Combination for door in "Find the source of power in Dead men's Resnite"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the Quest "Find the source of power in Dead men's Resnite", I'm stuck on the door with the combination.

Here are the "solutions" on the walls:

[image: http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/613842483416935081/922B3768BBACF02844530A13B2B396F7C16B93E5/]

And here is the door:
[image: And here is the door:]

What's the combination?

Comment: @Doozer Blake, PC tag was added spesificy to get around the "good" question system :)

Comment: See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35101/what-combination-do-you-set-on-the-door-to-open-it-in-the-claw). All doors that look like this require a claw to open, and the combination is viewable on the underside of the claw itself in your inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wall is a red herring: the Nordic puzzle doors are solved by [opening your inventory and rotating the claw around](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35625/what-is-the-solution-to-the-first-reachwater-rock-puzzle/35640#35640). You'll see the correct combination when you do.